# Rails Text Field Helper Returns Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails form helper that looks like this:

```
<%= text_field :username,nil, {:placeholder=>"new username", :value=>nil} %>
```

When I look at the HTML generated by this, it looks like:

```
input id="username_" name="username[]" placeholder="new username" size="30" type="text"
```

(HTML <> removed)

This makes accessing the username attribute troubling. I do:

```
@user.username = [:username]
```

Params looks like

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "username"=>["newusername"], "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"10"}
```

And @user.username gets set to (escaped) ["newusername"] - it gets set to "--- - newusername"

Can't figure out how to get rid of the [] around the form value! What should I do?

EDIT: Entire form as generated by rails:
http://tny.cz/0d5a9397

Comment: Can you paste the entire form?

Comment: Added a link to a pastebin with the entire form at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `text_field_tag`

```
<%= text_field_tag :username, nil, :placeholder => "new username" %>
```

using `text_field` somehow expects you to work on a resource.

```
text_field :user, :username
```

You can still use text_field but you have to explicitly set the name

```
text_field :username, nil, name: 'username'
```

What I didn't know was if you pass `nil` as the second argument, it will set that field as a collective tag so I learned something new today.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. What's the difference between text_field_tag and text_field?